# How to check the alignment of a text using playwright typescript

Tags: playwright, playwright-test, playwright-typescript

I want to validate if the text in my page is left or right aligned.

In selenium one can use `driver.findElement(By.id("id1")).getLocation().x;` to get the location of an element in the page based on which the alignment can be deduced.

What is the equivalent approach in Playwright?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on precise co-ordinates which is an fragile approach in my opinion , you may use [getAttribute](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-get-attribute) property to fetch the style(or some other property as applicable in your scenario) detail which confirms the alignment property per your use case.

```
let locator = page.locator("someText")

let styleValue = await locator.getAttribute('style')

expect(styleValue).toContain('left');
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like bounding box is similar to what you had in Selenium:

```
const box = await page.locator('#id1').boundingBox();
expect(box.x).toBeLessThan(100);
```

Comment: This approach was useful for elements (IMG tag) that dint have the style tag.